# Why isnt this code finding the column referenced in my .getDataRange?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to delete rows based on the value in the cells of column 'D' - row by row.

The for statement works fine and counts down from the last row with data in, as I know when deleting cells you should start from the bottom and go up.

But for some reason it keeps saying ''Cannot read property '3' from undefined.

I've tried moving the `.getDataRange`, tried changing it all to work on `.getRange` (no avail and more complicated) and I've changed the position of most of the code to see if that helps. Can not for the life of me find the solution to this.

```
function removeResolvedRows(){

 var snowData_dataRange = snowData.getDataRange().getValues()

 var snowData_lastRow = snowData.getLastRow()

 var nPDN = newPriorDayData.filter(String).length;

 var current_row = +nPDN

for (var n = current_row; n < snowData_lastRow; n--){      

 var status = snowData_dataRange[n][3];

if (status == 'Resolved'){

 snowData.deleteRow[n];

if (n == 0) break;

}                 
}
}
```

What I would like it to do is loop through the `[current_row][Column D]`, if it says Resolved, delete that row. Rinse and repeat until `current_Row == 0` then break. Currently it wont find column D.

Comment: I'm a VBA expert and not a Javascript expert by any means, but from my knowledge you should actually not commit to a top-down approach when deleting a list, and in your case, cells in a column. Were you to do this, the next iteration after deleting a cell would be 2 iterations ahead. Start from the bottom instead

Comment: Sorry! Im a newbie, my wording was incorrect. I meant what you said. Ill edit.

Comment: As ra89fi indicates, the issue is an out-of-bounds array access. Your `for` loop is incorrectly configured. Check its condition statement and the initial value of your index variable

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what these 2 lines are doing.

```
var nPDN = newPriorDayData.filter(String).length;
var current_row = +nPDN;
```

So I went for a simple solution that you can add stuff according to your needs. It checks for **Resolved** in D column and if found, deletes row.

```
function removeResolvedRows() {
  var values = snowData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rows_num = snowData.getLastRow();

  for (var n = rows_num; n > 0; n--) {
    if (values[n-1][3] == 'Resolved') {
      snowData.deleteRow(n);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked and was much simpler than the solution I ended up getting to work. The big issue it seemed was the code you mentioned being unnecessary & snowData.deleteRow having n in [] rather than ().

Comment: It should be `snowData.deleteRow(n);` and comparison should be `values[n-1][3] == 'Resolved'`, **not** `values[n][3] == 'Resolved'`